# How do I enable the IMAP functions in PHP?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, php5, imap, slicehost

I have a LAMP box running Ubuntu, Apache 2 and PHP5 with Slicehost. I'm a bit new to all this sysadmin stuff (I'm primarily a web developer).

I need to use the IMAP functions in PHP, but they don't seem to be enabled according to phpinfo(). How do I enable them?

All of the information I can find on the net says I need to recompile PHP to add it, but I don't have a clue how to do that.

Any advice would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, that depends on the distribution your LAMP server is running on. For example with Debian you can install the PHP5 IMAP module straight from the package manager with command `apt-get install php5-imap`.

Comment: I tried this, but the IMAP functions still don't show up in the php.ini (even after rebooting Apache and the whole server).

I played with a LAMP box a few years back with the original PHP and Apache and remember having to open php.ini and uncomment a line to activate a module - I can't see any sign of that now though.

Comment: What extensions are listed in php.ini or other ini files? Is there somewhere a line like

    extension=imap.so?

If not, just add it.

Comment: I re-performed your original suggestion, rebooted apache and it's now working - I must have cocked something up the first time. Thanks!

Comment: It's not enough to install it. You have to enable it as @JohnSimmonds mentionned.

Answer (score 10):

Carry out the following:

```
apt-get install php5-imap
```

However it's not enabled by default so enable it with:

```
php5enmod imap
```

Then bounce apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Done.

Comment: Yes, after enabling php module its working like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Check the PHP version:

```
$ php -v
```

Suppose shows 7.0.32. So your FastCGI Process Manager(fpm) tool version is 7.0

Now install IMAP ENABLE and ENJOY!! Follow below commands.

```
# sudo apt-get install php7.0-imap
# phpenmod imap
```

Restart & Enable service:

```
# sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm
# sudo systemctl enable php7.0-fpm
```

Check now.. IMAP is enabled!